# Defining a multivariable function to make it continuous at a point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am working with the function $f(x,y) = \frac{\sin(x)\sin^3(y)}{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}$ and am asked to make it continuous at $(0,0)$.

My approach was to take the limit along the line $x = 0$ and I got the limit to be $0$ and concluded that the function must be defined as $0$ at $(0,0)$ to make it continuous.

The question that I have now is whether it is right to do so or if there is any other curve along which the limit is not zero and in general what is the best way to work out such a problem where I need to find the continuity for a function with several variables.

Comment: Is there a special reason that the numerator is not written as $\sin^4(x)$?

Comment: @MartinR Good question! Mayby is it $\sin^3 y$?

Comment: Also the function should have two arguments: $f(x, y) = \ldots$.

Comment: the numerator is $sin(x)sin^3(y)$, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine, now we can observe that

$$\frac{\sin x\sin^3 y}{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}\frac{\sin x }{x}\frac{ \sin^3 y}{y^3}\frac{xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

then conclude by standard limits and evaluating the limit for the last factor

$$\frac{xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

which is clearly problematic at $(0,0)$.

Comment: the numerator should be $sin(x)sin^3(y)$, sorry for the typo

Comment: @AkashArjun I suspected it indeed. It doesn't change so much.I update it

Comment: Note that $1-\cos(x^2+y^2) \sim \frac 12 (x^2+y^2)^2$ at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: Sure. Unless I am mistaken, the function can *not* be make continuous at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes! Indeed I've lost an exponent. I fix it. Thanks